# How to connect MySQL date type with PHP date type using a loop

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I'm attempting to make a "this day in history" type of page using PHP and mySQL.  In the mySQL database, I have the following columns for each entry: id, date, topic, event.  The date column uses the mySQL date type which is YYYY-MM-DD.  I'm trying to use the date function in PHP to call the corresponding mySQL entry with the same date, but I can't figure out how to connect them.

This first section successfully returns everything from the database.

```
<?php

$config ['db'] = array (
'host'      =>  'localhost',
'username'  =>  'root',
'password'  =>  'root',
'dbname'    =>  'party'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'] , $config['db']['username'] , $config['db']['password']);

$query = $db->query("SELECT `events`.`date`, `topic`, `event` FROM `events`");

$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>', print_r($rows, true), '</pre>';
```

However, I don't want to display everything, just the row that contains the same month and day as the current date.  How would I properly loop through and display only the single row?  Here is where I ended.

```
//current day and month
$current_date = date("m d");

//select from database of events where matching month and day     
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `date` = :md ");

$statement->execute(array(':md' => $current_date));

//echo out events that happened throughout history
echo "On ", date('F jS'), ", the following events took place:";

while($rows = $statement->fetch()){

    echo $rows['topic'];
    echo $rows['event'];
}
```

The only thing it prints out is "On *current date*, the following events took place:"  Also, while it's not of upmost importance, my current date is printing out one day in the future.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you used date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); as your date for :md ?

Comment: Check your PHP timezone. That might be the reason for getting a day in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`d prefer to use mysql functions to extract month, day etc.

**Query:**

```
 SELECT * FROM events WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = MONTH(NOW())
 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) = DAY(NOW())
```

Try to check mysql time zone settings and php zone settings to figure out why time one hour ahead.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.  It's displaying the correct row even though my current date is displaying a day ahead.  I'm assuming that means that the time is off in my PHP and not mySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to select all events that occured on the same day and month but in different years. If so, your select statement should look like this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE MONTH(events.date) = 2 AND DAY(events.date) = 2
```

That will select all events occurred on Feb. 2

Now if you need to get only events that occurred on today's day and month then you don't need to pass any parameters at all and can do it totally in SQL this way:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE MONTH(events.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND 
    DAY(events.date) = DAY(CURRENT_DATE)
```